# JQuery: Help with ".live" and ".scroll"

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following JQuery:

```
$('#div1, #div2').scroll(function() { my_function($(this)); });
```

or

```
$('#div1, #div2').live('mouseover',function(){ my_function($(this)); });
```

What does `$(this)` represent?

Is it the DOM object of either DIV1 or DIV2? Or is it the HTML of that DIV?

What does "this" represent in the code above?

Answer (score 8):

`this` is the DOM element on which the event was fired, in this case `#div1` or `#div2`.

`$(this)` is a call to jQuery to wrap the DOM element in jQuery's wrapper, so you can use jQuery functions (e.g. `.text()`, `.bind()`, `.load()`) on it.

Answer (score 2):

`this` represents the DOM element that fired the event, either `#div1` or `#div2`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` will be the DOM element on which the event was fired (`#div1` if you mouseover `#div1`, ...)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this section of the jQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#using-dom-elements

In the context of any jQuery callback function, `this` is set to the DOM element being operated on by the function.  In your case, the callback function is operating on the one of the two DOM elements specified by your selector, either `#div1` or `#div2`.

As lonesomeday noted, in order to use jQuery operations on the element, you need to wrap it in the jQuery object.  That is what `$(this)` is.  It simply says "take this DOM element and give it to me in a jQuery object."

Be aware: a common gotcha when using `this` is changed context.  For example, if you were to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#div1').click(function() {
        var myThis1 = this;
        $('.divs').each(function() {
            var myThis2 = this;
        });
    });
});
```

`myThis1` would be the DOM object for `#div1`, but inside your `.each()` call, the context of `this` changes.  `myThis2` would, on each loop through, be set to a DOM object for the some element with the `divs` class.  Just something to look out for :)